# About a property about ordered n-tuple

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book 'A Course in modern mathematical physics' for Peter Szekeres. I read "an ordered $n$-tuple is a set in which the order of the elements must be specified." 
No problem till now , but just keep in mind its a 'set' but (special).
In Wikipedia, I've seen that one of its properties is that:
A tuple may contain multiple instances of the same element, so
tuple $(1,2,2,3)\neq (1,2,3)$, but set $\{1,2,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$.

I understand that a tuple shows the order of the elements in a set;  BUT its still a set , so what's the meaning of repeating the same element more than one time , what's the point of that?

Comment: Forget the "set".

Comment: Why should I forget the set. Even though in the wiki they didn't mention that its a set , but they've said that its a list of elements which is by means the definition of a set

Comment: Because thinking of a tuple as a set is confusing you.

Comment: If you want to find your seat in a movie theater you check both row and seat number. That's ordered pair. Repeating numbers has merit since there is third seat in third row, represented by $(3,3)$. And $n$-tuple is a set because everything is a set in mathematics.

Comment: An ordered $n$-tuple is an ordered sequence of $n$ entries. Of course, duplicates are possible. Usually, a set does not contain duplicate entries, so "set" is an unlucky way to name $n$-tuples, "list" would be much better.

Comment: Thank you everyone. And @Ennar your example is excellent. ..

Comment: @ZaKh, In math every object reduces to sets. But in your case I guess it is more like (not exactly an analogy) you can understand Newton's physics without Einstein's first. The concept of Cartesian's coordinates (2-tuples of real numbers) did not require Des Cartes to develop a set theory first :). Set theory only came out in existence through G. Cantor nearly in the beginning of the last century.

Comment: Aha.. good point @Gary thank you :)

Comment: If you want to be a bit more precise than the author was, you could replace “set” with “multiset” in the definition, which does allow for repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

An $n$-tuple is only a set for set theorists, since to them everything is a set.

For us ordinary mortals an $n$-tuple is a **function** $f:\>[n]\to X$, whereby $X$ is a predefined set. Such an $f$ is "datawise" completely determined in the form of the list $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ of its function values $x_k:=f(k)\in X$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$.